# FCM - Difference between Downstream Message and Upstream Message

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been studying materials related to Web push notification from FCM Messenger. While I came across downstream message and upstream message, apparently HTTP server only allows downstream message while XMPP server allows upstream message.

I have trouble understanding the difference between downstream and upstream message and the details are not well explained on FCM. I tried to search online but I have no luck. Please do help me as I am new to coding.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To put it on Layman's terms, **Downstream Messaging** is when you are sending a push notification from your App Server towards the Client App. However for FCM's case, you may send a downstream message without an App Server or by sending a usual curl request by making use of the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

While **Upstream Messaging** is the reverse, the Client App is sending a message towards your App Server. For this, the App Server is a requirement.

Do keep in mind that the FCM server is still in the flow (the *middle man*) that handles the queuing of your messages for both downstream and upstream.

Comment: I think this is pretty much the simplest explanation. Let me know if it's still confusing and which parts. I'll add in some more details.

Comment: Hi @AL,  Appreciate your explanation. From what I see from here, Upstream message is defined by a message sent from the client so it doesn't have anything to do with  the app server sending anything? But the downstream message can be sent only from app server to client serve.

Comment: Sorry I am not done with message. Basically to be more direct,

Comment: Downstream message is sending from point A to point B , whereas the upstream message is sending from point B to point A? There is nothing common between these at all?

Comment: AL, regardless i upvoted you but please do help to answer my following question. That would be great! :)

Comment: @JamesLee Your direct description of sending a message from point A to point B and vice versa is a good illustration. However, it'd be more appropriate to say that Downstream is Point A (App Server) sending a message to a single or multiple points (Client App instances/users/devices) while Upstream is Sending a message from different points (Client Apps/users/devices) towards a single point (App Server).

Comment: @JamesLee No worries. If my answer pretty much covers it all, do accept it so your post will be tagged accordingly. :) Cheers!

Comment: where we need specify our app server URL to receive upstream message from APP (via FCM)?