# Can we Demonstrate Upstream Messaging with help of only FCM and without Xmpp?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to demonstrate Upstream Messaging using FCM. If Firebase have their own cloud database and worked as backend server then why should we use XMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You need the App Server to work with Upstream Messaging.

The FCM server works only as a *middle man* in the flow for both Downstream and Upstream messaging (as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980725/4625829)). Like so, for upstream messaging:

```
Client App -> FCM Server -> App Server
```

Without your App Server, where would the FCM server forward the data that you need to process?

You could think of the FCM server as the part that handles the queuing of the messages between the two points.

Comment: As u say FCM is middle man and we can send downstream message without app server. Then how could my chat app transfer my messages using only firebase?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Are you using FCM alone for the chat app? It has to be only used for Push notifications. You should use the realtime database for the actual chat feature.

Comment: yes i am using realtime database for my chat app. But for my next task i have to demonstrate upstream and downstream messaging. I'm comfortable with downstream using "curl" but i have no idea about how to demonstrate upstream.